# Plugin: Reset simulation and track positions

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to make a plugin for a simple simulation that will check the position of two models relative to each other, and then reset after some time with the initial positions changed slightly.

What might be the best way to go about this? I am subscribing to the world_stats topic to get the sim_time and I figured out how to use physics::World::Reset(), but I can't figure out how to access model positions, or reset them before starting a simulation. Should I use a model plugin instead of a world plugin?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2659/plugin:-reset-simulation-and-track-positions/) by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 59 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can subscribe to the `~/pose/info` topic to see the poses of all moving models (the poses of stationary models don't get updated on this topic). You can also publish to the `~/model/modify` topic to set model poses. If you don't want to use topics, you can call world->GetModel and GetWorldPose, SetWorldPose from a world plugin. You just need to know the model names.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on 2013-05-14**:
This worked great! I will say that GetWorldPose & SetWorldPose were much easier to work with than publishing to ~/model/modify, since I didn't have to populate a full Model object.